# ¿jtable al tener muchos datos no se muestran?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

mi problema es que añadí un jtable, a este le he ingresado muchos datos, digamos que 41, al reproducir el proyecto en el jtalbe me muestra 39 y no me baja mas para ver los otros, que si están por cierto.
con una imagen me entenderán mas, creo que debe ser alguna opción en el panel o se podrá por código?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

llega hasta 31, si bajo con las flechas del teclado baja, pero no veo donde va.
estas son las opciones que tengo activadas por si puede ser algo de eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De dónde provienen esos datos?

Comment: de un bd sqlite

Comment: osea los datos si se cargan, porque yo bajos y hay sigue 32, 33,34, 32 el problema es que el acensor de la izquierda donde una baja para ver mas no baja mas, no se si me hice entender,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución:

```
nombreTabla.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
```

esto lo colocan para que inicie cuando abran el programa.

así lo resolví, de igual ustedes pueden ir probado cambiando el alto y el ancho

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).